# Showing server-side validation in ASP.NET MVC in jQuery modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

When using a jQuery modal dialog in asp.net mvc3. How would you redisplay the dialog after posting to the ActionResult and redisplaying serverside validation errors. In otherwords I would like to know how to display serverside errors in the modal dialog. Or redisplay the modal with server side validation errors after post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With regard re-displaying the dialog; don't. Leave it open and close it in an onsuccess handler from your (presumably) Ajax form. I suggest using a PartialView for the content of your dialog.

You can render the errors in your dialog by using `Html.ValidationSummary()`.